# pipe powershell script output to file

Tags: powershell, redirect, file-io, output, pipe

Scratching my head how to make this script send the output of the script to a text file identifying what groups were removed and what were not, below is my script anyone able to assist with what I am doing wrong?

```
 $adgroups = Import-Csv "c:\test\groups.csv"
 $logfile = 'C:\test\process.txt'
 $Stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($logfile)

 # Iterate through your List
 foreach ($group in $adgroups) {
    try { # try/catch for some sort of error handling
        Remove-ADGroup -Identity $group.Name ##.Name if your CSV column is named "Name"
        Write-Host "$group was successfully removed"
        $Stream.WriteLine($group + ' was successfully removed')
    } catch {
        Write-Host "$group wasnt removed"
        $Stream.WriteLine($group + ' wasnt removed')
    }
}
$Stream.Close()
```

I tried various ways of using $Stream to copy output to file

Comment: The construct `$group + ' wasnt removed'` (or alike) should lead to error *Method invocation failed because `[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]` does not
contain a method named '`op_Addition`'.* Try `$group.Name + ' wasnt removed'` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Does Out-File work for you?

e.g.,

```
Get-Process | Out-File -FilePath .\Process.txt
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.3